# Свой шаблонный класс для callback-ов в библиотеке (проблема с деструктором)

Tags: c++, winapi

И снова здравствуйте. Продолжаю понемногу писать свою GUI библиотеку под Windows, попутно изучая С++. Вычитал в различных источниках что экспортировать стандартные STL классы из своей библиотеки - не очень хорошо, ибо в дальнейшем это может вызвать всяческие сложности при использовании такой библиотеки в среде с другой версией STL (если на самом деле это не так - поправьте меня). Поэтому, чтобы не экспортировать std::function решил написать что-то вроде своего callback'а. В результате нескольких часов гуглирования удалось родить вот такой класс:

```
/**
 * \brief Частичное шаблонное объявление
 * \detail Обеспечивает возможность указания параметров шаблона в виде "ReturnType(Arguments...)" 
 * \tparam T Возвращаемый тип функции обратного вызова
 */
template<typename T>
class WQUERY_API Callback;

/**
 * \brief Класс-обретка над функцией (либо любым callable объектом) обратного вызова
 * \tparam ReturnType Возвращаемый тип функции обратного вызова
 * \tparam Arguments Аргументы функции обратного вызова
 */
template <typename ReturnType, typename ... Arguments>
class Callback<ReturnType(Arguments...)>
{
private:
    ReturnType(*wrapperFunction_)(Arguments... args, void*);  // Указатель на функцию-обретку (вызывает настоящий callable объект)
    void *pCallable_;                                         // Указатель на callabl'e объект объект

public:
    /**
     * \brief Конкструктор по умолчанию
     */
    Callback() :pCallable_(nullptr) {}

    /**
     * \brief Установка функции обратного вызова
     * \tparam T Тип callabl'e объекта
     * \param pCallable Указатель на функцию (callable объект)
     */
    template<class T>
    void Set(T pCallable)
    {
        // Выделить память под функцию (callable объект) и скопировать содежимое в эту память
        // если это лямбда, потребуется столько памяти, сколько занимают ее "захваченные" переменные
        this->pCallable_ = malloc(sizeof(T));
        memcpy(this->pCallable_, &pCallable, sizeof(T));

        // Создать функцию "обертку", которая инициирует вызов callable объекта с аргументами args
        this->wrapperFunction_ = [](Arguments... args, void *callable) ->ReturnType {
            return (*reinterpret_cast<T*>(callable))(args...);
        };
    }

    /**
     * \brief Вызов функции обертки
     * \param args Аргументы
     * \return Значение, возвращаемое оберткой (идентично тому что вернет pCallable_)
     */
    ReturnType Invoke(Arguments... args)
    {
        if (this->IsSet())
        {
            return this->wrapperFunction_(args..., this->pCallable_);
        }

        return ReturnType();
    }

    /**
     * \brief Сброс функции (очистить память и сделать не вызываемой)
     */
    void Unset()
    {
        if (this->pCallable_) {
            free(this->pCallable_);
            this->pCallable_ = nullptr;
        }
    }

    /**
     * \brief Установлено ли
     * \return Состояние
     */
    bool IsSet() const
    {
        return this->pCallable_ && this->wrapperFunction_;
    }

    /**
     * \brief Деструктор (срабсывает функцию)
     */
    ~Callback()
    {
        this->Unset();
    }
}
```

Планировалось что использоваться данная штука будет как-то так:

1)В классе Window (или в классах элементов управления) объявляется структура с набором объектов класса Callback

```
    struct
    {
        Callback<bool()> onClose;
        Callback<void()> onPaint;
        Callback<void(unsigned int type, Vector2D<int> newSizes)> onResized;
        Callback<void(unsigned int code)> onKeyDown;
        Callback<void(unsigned int code)> onKeyUp;
        Callback<void(char symbol)> onTyping;
        Callback<void(Vector2D<int> cursor)> onMouseMove;
        Callback<void(Vector2D<int> cursor, MouseKeys type)> onMouseKeyDown;
        Callback<void(Vector2D<int> cursor, MouseKeys type)> onMouseKeyUp;
    } events;
```

2) При использовании библиотеки будут указываться callback'и вот таким образом

```
wquery::Window window1;
window1.events.onClose.Set([]() {std::cout << "Test" << std::endl; return true; });
```

3) В оконной процедуре, в нужных местах, будет происходить вызов функций (если они установлены)

```
    case WM_CLOSE:
        if (window)
        {
            if(window->events.onClose.IsSet())
            {
                if (!window->events.onClose.Invoke()) return 0;
            }

            if(window->closesProgram_) PostQuitMessage(0);
        }
        ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
        break;
```

По началу все шло хорошо, в аргумент функции Set можно было отдать как лямбду, так и обычный указатель на функцию, и они отлично вызывались. Но вот вызов деструктора Window к сожалению начал порождать вот такую ошибку во время исполнения: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Оказалось что ошибку порождает именно освобождение памяти в самом классе Callback. А конкретно вот этот момент

```
    void Unset()
    {
        if (this->pCallable_) {
            free(this->pCallable_);
            this->pCallable_ = nullptr;
        }
    }
```

И мне пока-что крайне непонятно в чем тут проблема, ведь я не удаляю память к которой у меня нет доступа, я удаляю СКОПИРОВАННУЮ память (в функции Set идет именно копирование). Так же интересно что данный класс работает без проблем вне библиотеки. Может быть я упускаю какие-то важные детали во время этого самого копирования? А может следовало вообще иначе подходить к реализации своего callback'а?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут имеется сразу несколько проблем:

- В С++ не следует использовать `malloc`, а если все-таки используете, то следует проверять, что результат не `nullptr`
- Инициализация простым копированием байт легально может быть выполнена только для тривиально-копируемых объектов (например int, void *). Если у вас в качестве `T` будет какая-нибудь лямбда с захватом `std::string` то копия будет содержать потенциально невалидные указатели на буфер, которым владела исходная строка. В с++ следует вызваьть конструктор копирования. т.е. вместо

```
 this->pCallable_ = malloc(sizeof(T));
 memcpy(this->pCallable_, &pCallable, sizeof(T));
```

вызвать

```
 this->pCallable = new T{pCallable};
```

- Для класса `Callback` будет использован сгенерированный компилятором копирующий конструктор (и оператор присваивания), который просто скопирует значение указателя, которым владеет другой объект. Это приведет о ошибке двойного освобождения памяти. Следует написать свои варианты копирующего (перемещающего) конструктора (и оператора).
- В C++ не следует заниматься ручным удалением памяти - для этого существуют умные указатели.

Последние два пункта известны как [правило 3 / 5 / 0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Что касается использования такой библиотеки в среде с другой версией stl - к сожалению, трудности с бинарной совместимостью действительно имеют место быть. Причем даже между кодом собраным одним и тем же компилятором с разными параметрами. Такая обертка никак в этом плане не поможет. Единственным способом традиционно является использование минимального C api.

Comment: Спасибо за столь подробное пояснение. Я использовал там именно malloc а не new, так как потом в функции Unset проблематично использовать delete (нужно делать шаблонную, и деструктор получается тоже должен быть шаблонным). Но я еще над этим поколдую (может оберну это все в еще один класс внутри). Интересно также что все проблемы исчезают если использовать массив (например void * pCallable[4]). Я так понимаю он тогда выделят память в стеке (по байту на элемент?) и очистка происходит автоматически, правда тогда у передаваемой лямбды вроде как будет ограничение по кол-ву захватываемых переменных..

Comment: И раз уж подобная обертка бессмысленна в плане предотвращения проблем совместимости, будет ли более правильным реализовывать все это в виде статической библиотеки (то есть не dll, а именно когда все находится только в lib) или там тоже могут возникнуть проблемы? (lib ведь это тоже уже готовый бинарный код, который просто линукется но не компилируется каждый раз с проектом? или я не правильно понимаю?)

Comment: @AlexNem lib тут ничем не поможет. Статические библиотеки также должны четко соответствовать версии компилятора. И нет, lib это не готовый бинарный код, а просто архив с компиляторно-специфичными объектными файлами. При этом машинный код может генерироваться уже на этапе линковки.